# problem calling method from another script, Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a method ListItems() witch i want to be updated whenever I open the Inventory for my game in Unity. Whenever I try this I get the error: *member InventoryManager.ListItems() cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead*

None of these methods are static, so I'm a bit confused here...

ListItems() :

```
public void ListItems()
{
    foreach(var item in Items)
    {
        GameObject obj = Instantiate(InventoryItem, ItemContent);
        var itemName = obj.transform.Find("Item/ItemName").GetComponent<Text>();
        var itemIcon = obj.transform.Find("Item/ItemIcon").GetComponent<Image>();

        itemName.text = item.itemName;
        itemIcon.sprite = item.icon;
    }
}
```

Update() from a different class:

```
public GameObject inventory;
public InventoryManager i;

  public void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
    {
        InventoryManager.GetComponent<InventoryManager>().ListItems();
        inventory.gameObject.SetActive(!inventory.gameObject.activeSelf);
       
    }
}
```

Comment: `InventoryManager.GetComponent`? Is this the code pristine?

Answer (score 0):

Your `InventoryManager` is a reference to your script so you don't actually need to call the `GetComponent<InventoryManager>()`.

You just simply call it like this:

```
i.ListItems();
```

Or, if you want to use the `GetComponent<InventoryManager>()` you use it on the gameObject that your script is attached to, for example if `public GameObject inventory;` has attached to it the `InventoryManager` script then you can use the following code:

`inventory.GetComponent<InventoryManager>().ListItems();`

Using the [GetComponent](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html) method is performance heavy, and it's not required to call it everytime, you can call it only once at the `Awake()` or `Start()` method to get the reference that you want and then just simply use the cached reference.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!:) Would this not be possible to do if InventoryManager was a sigleton class?Earlier I tried some different things, and I was able to solve it calling "InventoryManager.i.ListItems()" in the Inventory class, where "i" is derived from the InventoryManager class.